# Formatar timedelta em template Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Estou tendo problemas em apresentar o tempo de uptime de um equipamento, o django automaticamente mostra no seguinte formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de apresentar este valor de tempo em português.

no `settings.py` as configurações de timezone estão da seguinte maneira:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

LOCALE_NAME = 'pt_BR'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

o template está assim:

```
<tr>
    <td>Uptime:</td>
    <td>{{ status.uptime }}</td>
</tr>
```

e o valor apresentado é obtido desta maneira:

```
obj['uptime'] = (datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0) - obj['last_up'])
```

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: Qual o tipo da variável que está sendo passada para o template? Como está o template?

Comment: o template está assim:

    <tr>
        <td>Uptime:</td>
        <td>{{ status.uptime }}</td>
    </tr>

e o valor apresentado é obtido desta maneira:

    obj['uptime'] = (datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0) - obj['last_up'])

Comment: atualiza seu post com o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi criando a seguinte função:

```
uptime = (datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0) - obj['last_up'])
obj['uptime'] = format_uptime(uptime)

def format_uptime(timedelta):
    total_seconds = timedelta.seconds

    days = total_seconds // (60 * 60 * 24)
    total_seconds = total_seconds % (60 * 60 * 24)
    hours = total_seconds // (60 * 60)
    total_seconds = total_seconds % (60 * 60)
    minutes = total_seconds // 60
    seconds = total_seconds % 60

    if days > 0:
        return f'{days} Dias {hours}h {minutes}m {seconds}s'
    else:
        return f'{hours}h {minutes}m {seconds}s'
```